# Can't cd via ssh script - Debian

Tags: shell, ssh, cd

I have one Debian 6 Server where it doenst work to run a cd commond through a ssh script.
It allways throws the error "cd: can´t cd to /home/user/directory/ \ Error: Unable to access jarfile name.jar"

I douple checked the permissions. They look all fine.

- 755 on every folder
- 644 on the script and jarfile
- home directory´s ownership is root:root
- subfolders and files ownership owns the user which runs the scripts (user:user)

The thing I dont understand is, that it works on my other three servers just fine and the setup is the same.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/
java -Xmx30M -Xms30M -XX:MaxPermSize=40M -jar Minecraft_RKit.jar
```

this also doesnt work:

```
DIRECTORY=$(cd "`dirname "$0"`" && pwd)
(cd "$DIRECTORY"; java -Xmx30M -Xms30M -XX:MaxPermSize=40M -jar Minecraft_RKit.jar ${USER}:${PASS})
```

Permissions:

```
Path: /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/

drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Sep  2 03:18 home
drwxr-xr-x 7 mcgameserver mcgameserver 4096 Sep  2 02:45 mcgameserver
drwxr-xr-x 11 mcgameserver mcgameserver 4096 Sep  2 01:56 unhinged
-rw-r--r--  1 mcgameserver mcgameserver      342 Sep  2 20:07 rtoolkit.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 mcgameserver mcgameserver   555336 Sep  2 01:08 Minecraft_RKit.jar
```

Error first script:

```
mcgameserver@3770-41:~$ sh /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh
: not foundeserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh: 2: /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh:
: not foundeserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh: 5: /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh:
/home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh: 9: cd: can't cd to /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/
Error: Unable to access jarfile Minecraft_RKit.jar
```

Error second script:

```
mcgameserver@3770-41:~$ sh /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh
: not foundeserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh: 2: /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh:
: not foundeserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh: 5: /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh:
/home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh: 8: /home/mcgameserver/unhinged/rtoolkit.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected
```

The same script is running on 3 other servers. They are all installed the same way by me.

Comment: You misspelled "directory" in the error message you showed us. Did you spell it correctly in your actual script? "*home directorys ownership is root:roo*" Do you mean "`/home` directory"? Do you mean "`root:root`"? There are so many typos in your question, it's nearly impossible to tell what the problem is. Please show us (a small version of) the actual script, along with the actual error message. Copy-and-paste as much information as possible; don't re-type it.

Comment: updated it. I hope it is now understandable

Comment: If the copy/paste of the error messages is faithful, looks like DOS carriage returns in your script file. Examine it with a hex dump tool, or simply see if `dos2unix` will fix it.

Comment: dos2unix helped, Thanks. How can something like this happen ? I just downloaded and uploaded it with winscp. I didn´t even open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If WinSCP is in *text* or *auto* [transfer mode](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_mode) the *End-of-line characters* setting in the [*Environment* dialog](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_environment) might have kicked in, possibly altering your  linebreaks.

Comment: Do you know where to change this ? Dont find it.

Comment: @user2693017 Don't you get the [login screen](http://winscp.net/eng/data/media/screenshots/login_environment.png) when you start WinSCP? It's the top option under "Environment" there. The transfer settings dialog is under "Options/Preferences/Transfer/Default transfer settings" in the actual program's menu.